# Creating extra reverse polyline in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, autocad

I want to create a piping network.

When I import my AutoCAD file in ArcMap, the program creates an extra reverse polyline.

For example if I have a polyline which is include 50 spot, the GIS draw a polyline from point 1 to 50 and another on from 50 to 1. Exactly reverse.

Can I solve this problem by specifying my first and last point before I import my file to GIS?

Comment: If your data generates double features, it's likely because they have double features. If it's systematic, then removing those features should be easy enough.

Comment: Do you know which line is correct? By some attribute?

Comment: Adding an image to your question, helps explain your problem.